# Revoke Access to certain user roles and admin pages

Tags: php

I'm building a website with WordPress, but it will be managed by more than 20 persons. What I want is to revoke access to each one without using a plugin.

I added in `functions.php` some code for those people who are not "administrators", I used code like this: `remove_menu_page("page X")`, but the problem is if they put following url in the browser: `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=testimonial` they still have access.

What should I do when a user is not the user I want. I want to use some code like this: `if($current_user->ID != '21') )`  he/she should be redirected to `wp-admin/index.php`.

My idea was trying to get the `page ID` or the `current url` but it is not working in the way I use the code.

I also need to mention that I installed a few plugins, and they add some extra menus like:  `edit.php?post_type=testimonial` or `edit.php?post_type=etheme_portfolio`.

All the users will be `administrator` but only I should be able to see all menus and having access to everything (As a `super admin`?). So even another `administrator` should not have access to everything in the backend when he has not `ID 1` (in this case that is me).

What I already did is removing following:

```
remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=testimonial');
remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=staticblocks');
remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=etheme_portfolio');
remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=essential_grid');
remove_menu_page('themes.php');
remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
remove_menu_page('users.php');
remove_menu_page('tools.php');
remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
remove_menu_page('themepunch-google-fonts');
remove_menu_page('wpcf7');
remove_menu_page('ot-theme-options');
remove_menu_page('yith_wcwl_panel');
remove_menu_page('vc-general');
remove_menu_page('mailchimp-for-wp');
remove_menu_page('revslider');
remove_menu_page('yit_plugin_panel');
remove_menu_page('about-ultimate');
remove_menu_page('essential-grid');
```

I hope my question is clear but if you have any doubts please ask.

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to wpse, I have edit your question a little (didn't want to make a complete overhaul) to make it more clear for other users to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this several ways, it just depends on how specific you want to get. Like do you need to disable for only one user with the ID of 21 or was that just an example? And are you trying to disable several pages or just a couple?

---

**Example 1:** ***You can do this to redirect the dashboard to the edit posts page if not an administrator.***

```
add_action('load-index.php', function(){
   if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
      if(get_current_screen()->base == 'dashboard')
         wp_redirect(admin_url('edit.php'));
   }
});
```

---

**Example 2:** ***Or for a lot of pages you could do something like this:***

```
function bw_redirect_admin_pages() {
    if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
      global $pagenow;
      $admin_pages = array(
                                'options-writing.php',
                                'options-reading.php',
                                'options-discussion.php',
                                'options-media.php',
                                'options-privacy.php',
                                'options-permalink.php',
                        );
      if(in_array($pagenow, $admin_pages)){
        wp_redirect( admin_url('/') ); 
        exit;
      }
   }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'bw_redirect_admin_pages');
```

---

> Sidenote : **If you need to be more specific on users you can use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)**

---

**Example 3:** ***You can also change individual capabilities for other users.***

Let's say **your** user ID is 1. Now you can use `map_meta_cap` and block certain capabilities from users who aren't you. So in this example below, your saying that if the user is not **user 1** (or whatever your ID is) than they can't delete or edit users.

```
add_filter('map_meta_cap', 'prevent_user_edit', 10, 4 );
function prevent_user_edit( $required_caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ){
    $protected_user = 1; // ID of user not editable (this should be YOUR user id)
    if ( $user_id === $protected_user ) // Don't block caps if current user = protected user
        return $required_caps;
    $blocked_caps = array(
        'delete_users',
        'edit_users'
        );
    if ( in_array( $cap, $blocked_caps ) && $args[0] === $protected_user )
        $required_caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    return $required_caps;
}
```

*Each admin menu and submenu is associated with a specific capability for different roles. So in the above example we disallow all users beside yourself to access the users page and also disallow them to delete users.*

**See the [Roles vs Capability table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) to decide what to block as well as the menus associated with those capabilities [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities).**

This is much safer than just "redirecting a page". The example above is a good demonstration of this. If only redirecting people away from the "users" page on page load, they'd still have the `delete_users` capability which you don't want.

You could then combine this example with one of the redirect ones if you wanted them to also redirect.

---

**Example 4:** ***Or another way to do the same thing above but with your email instead of your ID:***

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap',
function( $caps, $cap, $args ) {
    $user_id = $args[1];
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $email = $user->user_email;
    if ( $email != get_option('admin_email') )
        $caps['delete_user'] = false;
        $caps['edit_user'] = false;
    return $caps;
}, 10, 3 );
```

**[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) are some of the more common capabilities you can block**

**Example 5:** ***I highly suggest giving 20 people administration roles though. You'd be much safer creating a custom role:***

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'create_new_user_role' );

function create_new_user_role() {

    $add_role = add_role( 'manager', __( 'Site Manager' ),
            array(
                'read' => true,
                'edit_posts' => true,
                'edit_pages' => true,
                'edit_others_posts' => true,
                'create_posts' => true,
                'manage_categories' => true,
                'publish_posts' => true
            ));
}
```

---

**Example 6:** ***Change Displayed Role name***

If they absolutely must be have "administrator" role, you could do some trickery. I haven't actually tested this though.

```
function brw_change_administrator_role_name() {
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    // Change administrator role name to developer
    $wp_roles->roles['administrator']['name'] = 'Developer';
    $wp_roles->role_names['administrator'] = 'Developer';  

    // Change editor role name to administrator
    $wp_roles->roles['administrator']['name'] = 'Administrator';
    $wp_roles->role_names['administrator'] = 'Administrator';  


}
add_action('init', 'brw_change_administrator_role_name');
```

Similarly, you could also try this (although again not tested):

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'brw_translate_words_array'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'brw_translate_words_array'  );
function brw_translate_words_array( $translated ) {

     $words = array(
                        'Administrator' => 'Developer',
                        'Editor' => 'Administrator'
                    );
     $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
     return $translated;
}
```

Comment: I just updated the description for if it will makes more sense for you, I'm doing echo's and it shows me the ID of the user on the backend but for no reason is not doing the redirects. I'm doing a var_dump and it shows edit.php no edit.php?post_type=essential_grid that's the one I want to revoke access.

Comment: @Bryan I edit his question a little to make it a bit more clear what he/she wants to achieve (although it still needs to be reviewed by peer :) ). If I understand it correctly he want to have one `super admin` and 20+ others will be having the `administrator role` with reduced `capabilities`. (and yes `ID 21` is just an example if I am correct)

Comment: @Charles yes that's what I want :)

Comment: See my edit ARweaber, I think I understand what you want now.

Comment: Here's a bunch more examples I put together awhile back for doing these types of things. https://gist.github.com/bryanwillis/b2e558b395f2018f2eba#file-edit-pages-edit-theme-options-php-L4

Comment: @BryanWillis well the thing is i can get the admin id's the only is not working is revoke access to certain pages, once i'm into one of this pages i can detect if the user is not allowed to enter there but i can't revoke the access on that page. I can't create another role they want Administrators and also is easy for me to manage everything under the functions.php  , any ideas ?

Comment: @ARweaber, sorry bud been a long I'm having trouble understanding what your saying about revoking access and why you can't create another role. Is there something wrong with the second to last example I posted? Seems like the simplest option if I understand what you're asking, by blocking capabilities to users that aren't the admin email address (you).

Comment: Referring to the example with `remove_menu_page` in your question, is that ALL of the pages that you're trying to block for all users who aren't YOU?

Comment: @BryanWillis Hi Bryan, the thing is I'm allowed to put everyone under Admin Role ( boss decision ) so I want to add everyone under Admin Role but removing some pages on the left menu and also redirecting (revoke access) if they are trying to access to the list of pages I put before.

Comment: Ha OK I get it now... I've dealt with that before. Personally I'd just say it's a security risk to give that many people the admin role and is not how Wordpress is meant to work. That's probably not what you want to hear from me though. Why not create a role for yourself then? Like "developer" and give yourself total access. Then you can use one of the first few examples in the answer.

Comment: Also when you say revoke, do you want it to redirect to a the dashboard or something, or do you want it to tell them they don't have access or something like that?

Comment: @BryanWillis the thing is they are not going to see the menus like ( revolution slider ) but if someone for X reason know the url and he/she try to access he/she will be redirected to the dashboard. They need admin role because is going to be synchronized with an ERP. So i just need to have a function for if the ID's ( 2,3,4,5,6,7,9,X) are trying to access to the pages (x.php,y.php,etc.php) redirect to the dashboard.

Comment: @ARweaber you could use the [deprecated user levels](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels) and make all other admins have level 9 except yourself. Although, example number 3 above is your best option in my opinion. Also, what ERP are you using? Users shouldn't need the wordpress admin role just to access the ERP. Wordpress roles are based on capabilities, so all they should need is the capability that the ERP plugin requires and that is most likely editable if it's built correctly.

Comment: Technically the subscriber could have every wordpress capability and the administrator could have only the read capability. Roles are given capabilities which allows them access to certain pages/elements/etc. The reason this had gotten so complicated is because your trying to make wordpress work in a way it's not really designed to. Your erp should have a custom capabilities of it's own like `erp_edit_entries`, `erp_delete_entries`, etc.